# What feature must a CD-R drive have to add more information to a previously recorded CD-R disk?

Tags: cd-r

I'm thinking it’s either multi-session or Regional Code (RPC-1 or RPC-2)? I don't see how multi-speed would have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are talking about a [multi-session CD-R](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,25430,00.asp):

> Multisession recording is the process of adding data to a CD in
>   increments. Each track is recorded separately and then linked, so the
>   CD drive can read the tracks as if they were recorded in one session.

RPC (Regional Playback Control) codes—RPC-1, RPC-2, etc…—just control where recorded media can be played.  And multi-speed just refers to the speeds your CD-R can be written to.